# How to extract a DACPAC with a reference to another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, dacpac

I've got a database "[database01]" that I want to extract as a ".dacpac", but since one of my views got a JOIN to another database "[database02]", I get this error message:

"Validation of the schema model for data package failed.
Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[View01]: View: [dbo].[View01] has an unresolved reference to object [database02].[dbo].[table01]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in visual studio, the extract in ssms is very limited.

Create two projects one for each db and import each of them.